# error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)' after changing path of data dir

Tags: mysql, sockets, port, my.cnf, datadirectory

I am using mysql 5.6. I wanted to change the data directory for my database. So did following steps -

```
1. copy whole mysql folder from /var/lib/mysql/ to new folder named app.

2. Then grant permission to that folder.

3. stop mysql server.

4. changes in my.cnf for datadir =/app/mysql and socket variable = /app/mysql/mysql.sock

5. restart the server.
```

Now when I am trying to run mysql -uroot -proot it gives me following error -

```
'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
```

But when I can log in using following -

```
mysql -uroot -proot -h 127.0.0.1 or my system's IP or --socket =  /app/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Please let me know what I have missed.

**EDIT:**
When I am commenting socket variable in my.cnf. It is accessing mysql.sock from old path but working fine.

```
# socket = /app/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Is it correct to use it or I have to use from same data dir?

Comment: Try stopping MySQL and deleting the old `mysql.sock` entry. When you restart MySQL it should recreate the the socket file in the correct place.

Comment: @MikeW what about my.cnf file.? Do I have to change the value there  or it will automatic change?

Comment: The MySQL reference is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-mysql-sock.html)

Comment: I can see its recreating the mysql.sock in /app/mysql folder but still getting the error.

Comment: You probably have to set the new socket variable both path in server and client sections in my.cnf.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu I have already tried this one. Same problem.